# Ruby Sorting and removing duplicates from an array

Tags: ruby, sorting

Here is the list of item in my array: If you see there are files generated with the dates on them (e.g., `update.20130410.xml`). I should be taking only the latest file and remove the rest. Let's assume that the array values are sorted, so it should be fine if we are just picking the top item among the repeating pattern. Please help me.

Original array:

```
theOneBig.xml
theSecondFine.xml
theTestOne.xml
OtherImp.xml
mrss.xml
update.20130410.xml
update.20130402.xml
update.20120314.xml
update.20120313.xml
update.20120312.xml
update.20120301.xml
update.20130411.xml
file.update.20130410.xml
file.update.20130409.xml
file.update.20130409.xml
```

Output I would like to get is

```
theOneBig.xml
theSecondFine.xml
theTestOne.xml
OtherImp.xml
mrss.xml
update.20130410.xml
file.update.20130410.xml
```

Comment: What is "the latest file"? What would the output be when the duplicates are removed?

Comment: I updated the post, how i wanted my final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list is already sorted properly, the dates always begin and end with periods, and that you never have a sequence of digits beginning and ending with periods that *isn't* a date, then this should work (for Ruby 1.9.3):

```
original_array.uniq {|f| f.gsub(/(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)/, '') }
```

When you provide a block to `Array#uniq`, it uses the return value to determine "uniqueness".

Comment: Thanks Wally for your answer, but I am getting SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):20: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)/

Comment: It works with Ruby 1.9.3, but I got the same error as you using 1.8.7.

Comment: 1.8.7 regexes don't have look ahead/behind